# Ionic views with dynamic values

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic/Angular stack, I'm trying to create the accordion list  based on the following JSON data.

```
{  
   "parent":{  
      "url":"parent.html",
      "name":"Parent",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "type":"folder",
            "name":"Folder 1",
            "url":"folder1.html",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "type":"file",
                  "name":"File 1",
                  "url":"folder1-file1.html",
                  "children":[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "type":"file",
                  "name":"File 2",
                  "url":"folder1-file2.html",
                  "children":[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "type":"file",
                  "name":"File 2",
                  "url":"folder1-file3.html",
                  "children":[  

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "type":"folder",
            "name":"Folder 2",
            "url":"folder2.html",
            "children":[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            "type":"folder",
            "name":"Folder 3",
            "url":"folder3.html",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "type":"file",
                  "name":"Folder3 File1",
                  "url":"folder3-file1",
                  "children":[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "type":"folder",
                  "name":"Folder3 Folder1",
                  "url":"folder3-file1",
                  "children":[  
                     {  
                        "type":"folder",
                        "name":"Folder3 Folder1 Folder1",
                        "url":"folder3-folder1-folder1",
                        "children":[  
                           {  
                              "type":"file",
                              "name":"Folder3 Folder1 Folder1 File1",
                              "url":"folder3-folder1-folder1-file1",
                              "children":[  

                              ]
                           },
                           {  
                              "type":"file",
                              "name":"Folder3 Folder1 Folder1 File2",
                              "url":"folder3-folder1-folder1-file2",
                              "children":[  

                              ]
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And here is the sample I created http://codepen.io/udhayakumar/pen/BjWwPm ,now the problem is when item of depth 2 have children (items with the '+' symbol in the codepen sample), I have to load a new view with depth 2 as parent (that is items with '+') and items of depth 3 as its children.

The problem is how to load the same view again with the new values and so on when there is further children.

How to do implement this? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: codepen link is broken.

Comment: Please, fix your codepen url.

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya Sorry, the comma after the URL was the one broken that URL. It is fixed now..

Comment: @DavidePastore Sorry, the comma after the URL was the one broken that URL. It is fixed now..